# Curl - undefined references - using RestClientCpp

Tags: c++, curl, cmake, mingw, clion

I'm making an application that uses RestClient-Cpp on Windows, using MingW.
I built OpenSSL, and after that I tried to build Curl dynamically, but that failed, so I now have it built statically.
After that, I tried to build RestClient and that didn't give me any warnings.
Now in CLion, I'm using this CMake file;

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
# add_definitions(-DCURL_STATICLIB)
# find_library(curl NAMES curl libcurl)
# find_package(curl)
# add_definitions(-lcurl)
# find_library(restclient-cpp NAMES restclient restclient-cpp)
# add_library(curl STATIC IMPORTED)
# set_property(TARGET curl PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION C:/MinGW/lib/libcurl.a)
add_executable(project ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(project restclient-cpp)
```

The commented lines are some of the stuff that I tried to get it to work, but up until now, no luck...
I always get this error;

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../librestclient-cpp.a(librestclient_cpp_la-restclient.o): In function `ZN10RestClient3getERKSs':
c:\MinGW\stuff\restclient/source/restclient.cpp:45: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'
c:\MinGW\stuff\restclient/source/restclient.cpp:49: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
c:\MinGW\stuff\restclient/source/restclient.cpp:66: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_perform'
c:\MinGW\stuff\restclient/source/restclient.cpp:74: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_getinfo'
c:\MinGW\stuff\restclient/source/restclient.cpp:77: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'
c:\MinGW\stuff\restclient/source/restclient.cpp:78: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_global_cleanup'
c:\MinGW\stuff\restclient/source/restclient.cpp:50: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
```

when I'm linking... Any and all ideas are welcome...

Comment: I can't help with the CMake side of things, because I don't use it, but it looks very much like your application expects those symbols to be imported from a CURL.DLL, not from a static libcurl.a.  Make sure you don't have any `__declspec(dllimport)` attributes specified on the prototypes, either in your application, or in headers.

Comment: I have a curl.dll and a libcurl.dll too though. Is there some place specific I need to place these for it to work? I just plopped them down next to the static files...

Comment: I understand why you would have `curl.dll` -- it's the dynamically linkable library -- but what is `libcurl.dll`? If you're linking statically, you should have a static library, which would be called `libcurl.a`, and that should be in any directory in GCC's library search path, or in a directory path specified with GCC's `-L path/to/library` option. If you *are* linking dynamically, then you may have an *import* library called `libcurl.dll.a`, which goes where you normally install the static library, or you just put `curl.dll` there; you also need `curl.dll` in the same place as your `*.exe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved; CMake was using the libcurl.dll from my Git, so it was a different version to start with.
I also copied the libcurl.dll file to /mingw/bin and to /mingw/include and now it works as it should

Comment: Why put *any* DLL in `/mingw/include`? That's just *oh so* wrong! Headers belong in `/mingw/include`; libraries belong in `/mingw/lib`; DLLs belong in the same directory as the dependent `*.exe`, (or in a directory on `$PATH`, if they are intended to serve many different `*.exe`s in differing locations). For dynamic linking, you normally have an import library -- `libcurl.dll.a` in this case -- which may be placed in `/mingw/lib`, or you also need a copy of the DLL itself -- e.g. `curl.dll` -- where GCC will look for it *at build time*.

Comment: Well, apparently for some reason, thats where the dll file arrived for some reason...It explains why it didn't work... Thanks for the explanation :)